# async componentWillMount in react 16.3

Tags: reactjs

I have the following function that I use to tell if the user is authenticated:

```
  async componentWillMount() {
    this.setState({ busy: true });

    const authorisationProvider = this.props.authorisationProvider;

    const currentSession = await authorisationProvider.getSession();

    this.props.getUserAttributes();

    this.setState({ isAuthenticated: currentSession && currentSession.isValid(), busy: false });
  }
```

I then use `isAuthetnicated` in `render`:

```
  render() {
    if (this.state.busy) {
      return <LoadingOverlay busy={true} />;
    }

    return this.state.isAuthenticated ? this.props.children : <Redirect to={this.props.redirectTo} />;
  }
```

This seems like a bad way to do it and `componentWillMount` is being deprecated in react 16.3.

Can anyone suggest a way I could refactor this better?

Comment: you meant `componentWillMount` will be deprecated on 16.3, right? (check your second to last line: it reads `componentWillUnMount`.)

Comment: indeed, changed

Answer (score 0):

Use `componentDidMount`! You can set your state in constructor `this.state = { busy: true }` so that the first time you hit the `render()` function, you'll display the loading overlay.

Another approach is, again, on the constructor, check if the user is already authenticated (given the initial props you're receiving) and conditionally initialize the `busy` state. Something like this:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  const busy = !props.isAuthenticated;
  this.state = {
    busy: busy,
  };
}
```